# How do I add hotkeys or key actions to items in a listview when they have focus?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

`I am using Flutter Desktop (Windows 10) with Flutter 3.0.1`

In a flutter `listview.builder`, I can add `InkWell` to each item and when focused, I can press `Enter` or `NumpadEnter` keys to launch the `onkey` event.

But I want to add different keypresses like `Numpad Add` or even an `A` key press action to launch a different action, how do I do that?

basically, I can press `Enter` key when I have focus of an item to launch it's `onTap` event, but how can I add other kinds of `key presses` to launch `different events`?

currently I have only found this solution (wrap in RawKeyboardListener):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: RawKeyboardListener(
          focusNode: FocusNode(),
          onKey: (event) {
            if (event.logicalKey.keyLabel == 'Arrow Down') {
              FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
            }
          },
          child: const TextField(
            autofocus: true,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          // remove rawKeyboardListener here to prevent weird navigation skips
          return RawKeyboardListener(
            focusNode: FocusNode(),
            onKey: (keyEvent) {
              if (keyEvent.logicalKey.keyLabel == 'Numpad Add') {
                print('numpad clicked item $index');
              }
            },
            child: InkWell(
              focusColor: Colors.blue,
              onTap: () => print('clicked item $index'),
              child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child:
                      SizedBox(height: 50, child: Text('this is item $index'))),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

it works! BUT it has an issue where `if I scroll pass it's vertical view`, it then `starts to skip item focus`, like if I scroll down down down then scroll up then scroll down, the focus gets messed up.

You can copy paste the above code to test, only by removing the `RawFocusKeyboard` from each item in the listview, can solve this focus problem.

Has anyone found a better solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using RawKeyboardListener on the Inkwells, I used the Shortcuts and Actions widgets.

```
ListView.builder > Shortcuts > Actions > Inkwell
```

This fixed the scrolling errors and I can finally use a key shortcut other than `space` or `Enter keys`.

**the minor issue for future readers...**

When you are changing the focus of the items by using Tab, the Inkwell widgets can react to the shortcut keys like Enter key, Space key, and whatever you have assigned in Shortcuts and Actions widgets, but after you tap/click the Inkwells manually, no shortcuts will work (I suspect from my testings, the reason is the focus is not given to the Inkwell even if you manually tap it) I have yet to find the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining focusNode inside the build method of stateful widget(which will be recreated). Define it above build method and mark it final.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();//Define focusNode here
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: RawKeyboardListener(
          focusNode: FocusNode(),
          onKey: (event) {
            if (event.logicalKey.keyLabel == 'Arrow Down') {
              FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
            }
          },
          child: const TextField(
            autofocus: true,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          // remove rawKeyboardListener here to prevent weird navigation skips
          return RawKeyboardListener(
            focusNode: _focusNode,
            onKey: (keyEvent) {
              if (keyEvent.logicalKey.keyLabel == 'Numpad Add' && _focusNode.hasFocus) {
                print('numpad clicked item $index');
              }
            },
            child: InkWell(
              focusColor: Colors.blue,
              onTap: () => print('clicked item $index'),
              child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child:
                      SizedBox(height: 50, child: Text('this is item $index'))),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: when I press the NumpadPlus key, it prints the entire listview action hahahaa. something is definitely wrong.

Comment: That's because all elements in the list has got the listener and each element is printing it

Comment: but I only want to print the action on the focused item, how can I do that?

Comment: Add _focusNode.hasFocus. Edited my answer

Comment: nope, it still prints the entire list to me. my logic says this is because the entire item list has the same focus.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case and I was able to listen to key events using Shortcuts and Actions. In the below code sample, I am

- navigating focus of list items using arrow keys
- removing focus using esc
- selecting using the return key

###### Heres the output of the below code

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter ListView Example'),
        ),
        body: MyListView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyListViewState createState() => _MyListViewState();
}

class _MyListViewState extends State<MyListView> {
  late FocusNode _focusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode = FocusNode();
    focus = List.generate(count, (index) => FocusNode());
    _previousAction =
        _CallbackAction<PreviousIntent>(onInvoke: handlePreviousKeyPress);
    _nextAction = _CallbackAction<NextIntent>(onInvoke: handleNextKeyPress);
    _selectAction =
        _CallbackAction<SelectIntent>(onInvoke: handleSelectKeyPress);
    _unFocusAction =
        _CallbackAction<UnFocusIntent>(onInvoke: handleUnFocusKeyPress);
  }

  void handlePreviousKeyPress(PreviousIntent intent) {
    if (selected == null) return;
    print("previous press  $selected");
    if (selected! > 0) {
      selected = selected! - 1;
      focus[selected!].requestFocus();
    }
  }

  void handleNextKeyPress(NextIntent intent) {
    print("next press $selected");
    if (selected == null) {
      selected = 0;
      focus[selected!].requestFocus();
      return;
    }
    if (selected! < count - 1) {
      selected = selected! + 1;
      focus[selected!].requestFocus();
    }
  }

  void handleSelectKeyPress(SelectIntent intent) {
    if (selected == null) return;
    print("select press $selected");
  }

  void handleUnFocusKeyPress(UnFocusIntent intent) {
    if (selected == null) return;
    print("esc key press  $selected");
    // we should always have focuso on a listview
    _focusNode.requestFocus();
    selected = null;
  }

  int? selected;
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  int count = 5;

  late final _CallbackAction<PreviousIntent> _previousAction;
  late final _CallbackAction<NextIntent> _nextAction;
  late final _CallbackAction<SelectIntent> _selectAction;
  late final _CallbackAction<UnFocusIntent> _unFocusAction;
  List<FocusNode> focus = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Shortcuts(
        shortcuts: <LogicalKeySet, Intent>{
          LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowDown): const NextIntent(),
          LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowUp): const PreviousIntent(),
          LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter): const SelectIntent(),
          LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.escape): const UnFocusIntent(),
        },
        child: Actions(
          actions: <Type, Action<Intent>>{
            NextIntent: _nextAction,
            PreviousIntent: _previousAction,
            SelectIntent: _selectAction,
            UnFocusIntent: _unFocusAction,
          },
          child: Focus(
            autofocus: true,
            focusNode: _focusNode,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount:
                  count, // Change this to the number of items in your list
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  focusNode: focus[index],
                  tileColor: selected == index
                      ? Colors.grey // Change the color for the focused item
                      : null,
                  title: Text('Item $index'),
                  subtitle: Text('Subtitle $index'),
                  onTap: () {
                    // Handle item tap
                  },
                  onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
                    if (hasFocus) {
                      _focusNode.debugLabel = index.toString();
                    }
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class _CallbackAction<T extends Intent> extends CallbackAction<T> {
  _CallbackAction({required void Function(T) onInvoke})
      : super(onInvoke: onInvoke);
}

class NextIntent extends Intent {
  const NextIntent();
}

// action to move to the next suggestion
class PreviousIntent extends Intent {
  const PreviousIntent();
}

// action to select the suggestion
class SelectIntent extends Intent {
  const SelectIntent();
}

// action to hide the suggestions
class UnFocusIntent extends Intent {
  const UnFocusIntent();
}
```